# MVC custom controller Context.User is anonymous when authenticated

Tags: context-user

Any idea why Sitecore 9.3 would not pick up authenticated information of the user on a simple custom MVC controller method? I am trying to get the currently logged-in user, but it is showing `Sitecore.Context.User` as `extranet\Anonymous` even though the user is logged in. Cookies are being sent with the request.

I am guessing for some reason the request is not passing through `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.UserResolver, Sitecore.Kernel` in the `HttpBeginRequest` pipeline.

Any ideas? I feel like this is a simple one.

Comment: If you are logging in the user with FederatedAuth , try checking Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated or IsLoggedIn methods

Comment: IsAuthenticated was false, which I think we would expect when user is considered anonymous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the `page` (URL path) in which you're reading `Sitecore.Context.User` is in a Sitecore `site` that does not use the `security domain` that the user logged in to. E.g. your user logged into the `sitecore` security domain, but the web page you're testing is in your main public site, which doesn't use that security domain. This is a new issue I've discovered in Sitecore 9.3 vs. 8.2.

Comment: This was the issue. The api call was going to /sitecore/api... This did not match a site url and thus resolved to the "website" site. By changing the url to /sitecore/admin/api... the site resolved correctly and picked up the security information. Thank you for the pointer.